# function returning empty (scope issue)

Tags: java, json

I'm doing a simple 'get' using ASyncHttpClient and its working and giving me the correct json response in the onSuccess() function, but when I try to save the string response to a variable and return that variable in the function, it always returns an empty string.

Code:

```
public class HttpRequests 
{   
    public String jsonString = "";

    public String add_guest(String name, String id, String hardware_id) 
    { 
        AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
        String url = "http://www.mysite.com/api.php?name="+name+"&id="+id+"&hardware_id="+hardware_id;

        client.get(url, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(JSONObject response)
            {
                jsonString = response.toString();
            //this successfully ouputs the json response in LogCat
                Log.d("response:",jsonString);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable e) 
            {
                Log.d("http error:",e.toString());
            }
        });
        //this returns ""
        return jsonString;
    }
}
```

Its as if the jsonString inside the onSuccess isn't in the same scope as the jsonString I'm returning. The reason behind this is I have many api calls and want to keep them all in the same class, then call them from other various classes when I need them and just parse the json from there. I tried returning the json object too instead of the string but same deal as this.. it just comes out blank from the other class. (its not setting it properly in onSuccess)

Any ideas..?

**EDIT:**

Sorry I should have clarified. I AM calling add_guest from my other class. This is from my other class:

```
String response = "";
HttpRequests myRequest = new HttpRequests();
response = myRequest.add_guest("bob","1","123");
```

Now by calling add_guest this should in turn call the JsonHttpResponseHandler which 'should' set jsonString to the response and return it.. unless I'm missing something..

Comment: Does `client.get()` wait for the response to come in before executing anything after in the `add_guest()` method or is it completely independent? If it's completely independent, `jsonString` is returned immediately and 99% of the time will be `""`. By the way returning `""` is not the same as `null`.

Comment: Oh sorry I rewrote some of it in the editor and was originally setting it to null. But anyway - I think it may be independent.. assuming it is, is there a way around this..? Thanks AC :)

Comment: How are you using the value?

Comment: Well the result of each api call will be used differently.. but the majority will be used to retrieve text/images based on that specific users account (once they have logged in) so I need to have full access to the json string/object in code to manipulate the values.. Which is why I was calling it from my main class where I need to work with the response etc. to elaborate - the UI is never being changed on the fly.. these are 1 time requests that only happen once on page load. or when a user clicks a button.

Answer (score 3):

Let's take a close look at your code:

```
public class HttpRequests 
{   
    public String jsonString = "";
```

This declares a member variable named `jsonString` and initializes it to an empty String.

```
    public String add_guest(String name, String id, String hardware_id) 
    { 
        AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
        String url = "http://www.mysite.com/api.php?name="+name+"&id="+id+"&hardware_id="+hardware_id;

        client.get(url, new JsonHttpResponseHandler()
```

This creates a `JsonHttpResponseHandler` object which will be called when the response is available. Note that *none* of the code in this handler is executed yet. The object is only created.

```
        {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(JSONObject response)
            {
                jsonString = response.toString();
            //this successfully ouputs the json response in LogCat
                Log.d("response:",jsonString);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable e) 
            {
                Log.d("http error:",e.toString());
            }
        });
        //this returns ""
        return jsonString;
```

As your comment states, this returns `""` because none of the handler code has executed. You need to find a way to give the caller the String after the handler has finished.

```
    }
}
```

**Further Suggestions:**

After seeing the code which calls `add_guest()`, one possible solution that comes to mind is to change `add_guest()` to return `void` and add another method to `HttpRequests` called `getResponse()`. This method can wait for the response and then return `jsonString`. In order to do this, you will probably need to declare `AsyncHttpClient client` as a member variable, rather than local to `add_guest()`. I am unfamiliar with the `AsyncHttpClient` class, but I suspect that it has a method that will block until a response has occured.

Another possible solution is to add a `HttpRequests(JsonHttpResponseHandler)` constructor. Then the class which calls `add_guest()` can implement `JsonHttpResponseHandler` (assuming that it is an interface, not an abstract class) and get the response directly.

Comment: I edited my post including my code which calls the function. And regarding the "You need to find a way to give the caller the String after the handler has finished.", I know that's why I posted this :P

Comment: @tajonny07 I wrote that because I don't have enough information about your design. The solutions to consider are entirely a design issue. Let me see if I can come up with some ideas at least to help point you in the right direction.

Comment: @tajonny07 I edited some suggested solutions. They are off the cuff, so I hope they make sense.

Comment: I didn't mean any offense by that btw. I plan on having 10-15 of these get calls which all return json responses.. and I just need to be able to call a specific function, and have it return the (jsonObject or json string) from the result. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I'll give them a shot. PS - if you know a more efficient/easier way to do this GET call feel free to share :P I'm not biased towards using AsyncHttpClient, I just thought that was the correct thing to do to achieve this.

Comment: @tajonny07 I'm not familiar with any of these classes. My answer is only based off of an educated guess about the order of execution of your code.